# Data imputation and it's effects

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-imputation

For example, say someone wants to build a classifier that predicts if customers will come again to make another purchase in his store, anytime during the coming month.
The data contains 400 observations (400 customers), with features of Age and whether the customer did or did not come back to buy again (anytime during the coming month).
However, the Age features contains 180 missing data, so what the store owner did he calculated the median of the remaining 220, and filled the missing data with this age median.

After that the store owner separates the data to train and test as usual, builds the algorithm, and gets 90% accuracy on the test set.

What could be the problem with the algorithm or the way the store owner managed the data? will the accuracy still be this high when the model meets some new data ?

Comment: Is this a homework or textbook problem? If so, please add the [tag:self-study] tag and read its tag wiki.

Comment: If the model is that accurate with more than half of the ages imputed, age is probably a weak predictor.